# How to display number/text outside of container

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I want to add some custom css/html to my site so that list posts (Top 10 best vacations, etc) have numbers that are outside of the column. For instance instead of the normal

|1. New York

|

|2. Florida

|

|3. Hawaii

|

I would like it to look like

1 |New York

|

2 |Florida

|

3 |Hawaii

|

I want the numbers to be really large, but not screw up the formatting of the text. I've seen places like the New York Times do this with quotes, images, etc.

I tried this code:

```
.list-number{
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Merriweather'; 
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    font-size: 5.5rem;
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    width: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

And it moved the number to the left, but the number disappeared as soon as it went off the container. It also left behind the paragraph of space where it would have been.  I've been tinkering with this for an hour and I'm not sure what needs to change.

(When this is resized for mobile, I planning on @media query changing it to normal -- but haven't gotten that far yet.)

Comment: Start with the very quick and simple 'list-style-position: outside'. If that's acceptable, it's a very quick change. If you want it to be subtly different, it's going to be a lot more work.

Comment: In case you have an ordered list, try something like: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this answer even for unordered list.

Use an item counter and place it before list item within `::before` pseudo-element

```css
li {
    width: 150px;
    background: orange;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  counter-reset: num;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: num;
    content: counter(num);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    margin: -5px 20px -5px -25px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: yellow;
    background: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>item1</li>
 <li>item2</li>
 <li>item3</li>
 <li>item4</li>
 <li>item5</li>
 <li>item6</li>
 <li>item7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, but *only* if I change to position: absolute; -- any idea why? When I have position: relative; nothing is visible at all

Answer (score 1):

If you use a custom counter and absolutely position the bullets in `:before` elements you could format this however you like:

```
.list-number li{
    position:relative;
    counter-increment: counter;
}

.list-number li:before {
    content: counter(counter);
    position: absolute;
    left: -80px;
}

.list-number{
    list-style:none;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Merriweather'; 
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    font-size: 5.5rem;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 100000;
    padding: 0 0 0 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bq7at1g1/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this example here i have created two containers a parent div and a child span and positioned the span relatively to the left with a negative value:

```css
.parent{
  background-color:red;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin-left:10px;
  
}
.child{
  position:relative;
  left:-15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="child">
    1 Hello
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sadly this isn't a good solution. Better start learning `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this.
http://codepen.io/Elysium13/pen/qROpZN

```
body {
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
}
.section-block{
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0 25px 0 25px;
  background-color:white;
  border-bottom:1px solid #f8f8f8;
}
.section-block .list-no{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-33px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#5bc0de;
}
.section-block .list-title {
  display:inline-block;
  color:#aaa;
  margin:0 0 5px 0;
}
.section-block .list-description {
  margin-left:15px;
  color:#111;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <section class="section-block">
      <span class="list-no">1</span>
      <h4 class="list-title">New York</h4>
      <br>
      <small class="list-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</small>
    </section>
    <section class="section-block">
      <span class="list-no">2</span>
      <h4 class="list-title">Florida</h4>
      <br>
      <small class="list-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</small>
    </section>
    <section class="section-block">
      <span class="list-no">3</span>
      <h4 class="list-title">Hawaii</h4>
      <br>
      <small class="list-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</small>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```